# what's wrong with my axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

at fetch.js

```
export default async(url = '', type = 'GET') => {
    ...
    if (type == 'GET') {
        await axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)//get the right value
            return response
        })
    }
}
```

at getData.js

```
  import fetch from '../config/fetch'
  export const getDia = () => fetch('...', {
  });
```

at kBase.vue

```
async initData(){
   let res = await getDia();
   console.log(res)// console undefined
}
```

I can get the data in the console from `fetch.js` but I just cannot get the data in `kBase.vue`. Can you tell me how to fix this. Thx

[image]

Comment: you have to import getDia.js in kbase.vue

Comment: I had been import that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to return the value of the request from the `then` block. But you use `await`. So try this:

```
export default async(url = '', type = 'GET') => {
    ...
    if (type == 'GET') {
        try {
            var res = await axios.get(url)
            console.log(res.data)
            return res
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Some error...', error)
        }
    }
}
```

[ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await ]